# How do I express a second order restriction upon a third order comprehension schema?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, modal-logic

I want a third order $\Pi^2_1$-comprehension schema so that $\alpha$ in 
$$\forall x_1,\ldots,x_k, X_1,\ldots,X_l,\Psi_1,\ldots,\Psi_m\exists \Upsilon\forall Y(\Upsilon Y\Leftrightarrow\forall \Phi\alpha(x_1,\ldots,x_k, X_1,\ldots,X_l,Y,\Psi_1,\ldots,\Psi_m, \Phi))$$ is at most a Boolean combination of $\Pi^1_1$-sets; actually, I only need $\alpha$ to be $\Sigma^1_1$, but a restriction to $\Sigma^1_1$ seems unprincipled here.  (Compare to these matters the related question I posed: [Can a Boolean Set Algebra be Restricted in the Analytical hierarchy?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/267307/can-a-boolean-set-algebra-be-restricted-in-the-analytical-hierarchy))  How do I, in presence also of the second order $\Pi^1_1$-comprehension schema $$\forall x_1,\ldots, x_n, X_1,\ldots, X_k\exists Y\forall a(a\in Y\iff\beta(a, x_1, \ldots, x_n, X_1, ..., X_k)),$$

best state such a second order restriction as I want upon the third order comprehension principle?